# MS Access query in VB 2010 involve date range

Tags: date, range

i am at wits end. have look many forum but not found.

Am trying to query data from an Access db using VB 2010 System.Data.OleDb object. 
Below is the code :

```
Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT format( dateadd(""m"", -e.tenure, e.expirydate), ""yyyy-mm-dd"")  as Expired, n.customerid , e.type as Description, (select s.type from servicetype s where s.servicecode = e.servicecode) as CodedType,  (select v.servicecode from servicetype v where v.servicecode = e.servicecode) as ServiceCode, e.totalamount INTO [Excel 12.0 Xml;DATABASE=d:\BookTest.xlsx;HDR=Yes;].[Sheet1] " _
        & " From notification n, notificationservice e where " _
        & " e.notificationid = n.notificationid " _
        & " and mid(n.notificationid, 1,2) ='RN' " _
        & " and jn_duplicate = 0 " _
        & " and dateadd(""m"", -e.tenure, e.expirydate) between @1 and @2 " _
        & " and ( n.salesid is null or ( n.salesid is not null and not exists 
          ( select paymentid from payment p where p.invoiceid = n.salesid) ))  ", _
        m_conn)


        AccessCommand.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime(2013, 7, 21) '"#20-jul-2013#"  '(InputBox("Enter Expiry DateFrom in dd-mon-yyyy", "", "", 100, 100))
        AccessCommand.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime(2013, 7, 31) '"'#30-jul-2013#"  '(InputBox("Enter Expiry DateTo in dd-mon-yyyy", "", "", 100, 100))
```

But try as many combinations, i am always getting error like no data specified etc..

My objective is to ask user to key in two dates that would form the Date From and Date To in the query having between dates.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks
Cho

Comment: "...error like no data specified etc." is a bit unclear, could you post the exact error message?

Comment: the error is "no value given for one or more required parameters." this error is trapped by the exception catch that i included.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs on configuring parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx);

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB and .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC do not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure. In this case, you must use the question mark (?) placeholder, as in the following example.

In other words, for OleDB you need to replace `between @1 and @2 "` with `between ? and ? "` and just rely on the order of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much , but still my problem unsolved because the # character when appended to the date which is obtained by inputbox is still giving blank. but wehn i put into the query the full date ... date between #07/21/2013# it works...

Comment: I don't think the `#` should be there when parameterizing the query, try with just the date.